# Google Sign-In Button can barely be customized with new "Google Identity Services library"

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to add Google Sign-in to my website. Apparently it used to be possible to create your own completely customized Google sign-in button and have the onClick trigger a Google function that kicked off the Google Sign-in. But the "Google Sign-In platform library" has been deprecated, and the new "Google Identity Services library" doesn't have this option; it seems that you MUST use renderButton now, which gives you very limited customization options. You can't even change the font. (There's a .prompt() method for One Tap, but there are many cases in which One Tap doesn't show.)

So now if I want to have Google log in on my website, I can't match it to my website's theme, and if I have multiple social sign in options, e.g. Google, Facebook, Github, I either have to leave them looking mismatched or have them all match Google's look.

But if you see Airbnb's login options, they're still able to customize the button, so that all three fit with their website's theme. Are they just using the deprecated library? I read somewhere that the deprecated library won't work with any newly created API keys.

[image]

Am I stuck with ugly social log in buttons?